# How to display Calculations in a view ASP.net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a WPF app which Im trying to move to ASP.net framework, I am new to ASP.net and need some help displaying certain variables and calculations in a view. This is the class that i used previously in the WPF app which gets values, calculates them and then displays the to string method in a listbox.

```
{
    public class Module
    //Getters and setters for variables
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public int ClassHours { get; set; }
        public int HoursSpent { get; set; }
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
        public string WorkingDate { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public double StudyHours;
        public double RemainingStudyHours;

        //default constructor
        public Module()
        {

        }
        //constructor for class variables
        public Module(string code, string name, int credits, int classHours, int hoursSpent, int weeks, string workingdate, string username)
        {
            Code = code;
            Name = name;
            Credits = credits;
            ClassHours = classHours;
            HoursSpent = hoursSpent;
            Weeks = weeks;
            WorkingDate = workingdate;
            Username = username;

            // assigning method with necessary parameters to variables 
           StudyHours = CalculateStudyHours(credits, classHours, weeks);
           RemainingStudyHours = CalculateRemainingStudyHours(credits, classHours, weeks, hoursSpent);
        }

        //Method calculating study hours
        public double CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int classHours, int weeks)
        {
            return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;
        }

        //method calculating remaining study hours
        public double CalculateRemainingStudyHours(int credits, int classHours, int weeks, int hoursSpent)
        {
            int value = (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;
            return value - hoursSpent;
        }

        //ToString method displaying the object and details
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Code + "\n" + Name + "\n" + "Credits: " + Credits + "\n" + "Class hours per week: " + ClassHours + "\n" + "Requires " + StudyHours + " hours of self study per week." + "\n" + 
                "Based on your hours spent working on this module you have: " + RemainingStudyHours + " remaining hours left ";
        }


    }

}
```

I want to be able to display the calculations like this format for example:
but instead have the calculation variables in the table and their own heading names
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYlmh.png)

Any tips on how to approach this correctly will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you using older webforms, or newer MVC.

However, you can send a collection of "class" instances to a grid.

Say we have this markup:

```
    <div style="padding:25px;width:60%">
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"></asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </div>
```

(i included cssClass="table" - and that will bootstrap format the table.

So, assuming your class, then if we were to write say this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        List<Module> MyModules = new List<Module>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            Module OneMod = new Module("PROG512", "Programming 512", 15, 10, 5,20, "2021-11-23","joe");
            MyModules.Add(OneMod);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = MyModules;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Now, I would assume that the actual data comes from a database, and you would loop th table, feed the values to the above class "list" and then shove the resuts into the GridView.

But, the above idea is quite much the "common" approach.

I just pasted in your class, typed in above, and ran it with the results as per above.